# gtk+ v3 return control to the main for redrawing

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

i have a piece of code in function called `check_pwd` that do:

```
if(g_strcmp0(s1,s2) != 0){
   gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(a), "error");
   return -1;
}
else{
   gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(a), "ok");
   //other things
}
```

While the "error" message is displayed because the program return the control to the main function, how can i show the "ok" message?

Comment: you don't give enough details to give a meaningful answer. what is "// other things"? you're blocking the main loop in there? you should never block the main loop in GTK+, but use source like idles and timeouts to inject your own code: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just run the main loop:

```
while(gtk_events_pending())
  gtk_main_iteration();
```

[See the GTK+ documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-events-pending), which recommends the above with:

> Checks if any events are pending.
>
> This can be used to update the UI and invoke timeouts etc. while doing some time intensive computation.

Comment: but this not always work and i read that it isn't a good pratice to re-run the main because you can have re-entry issue!

Comment: @polslinux As far as I know, this is the recommended way of making a blocking process still responsive in the UI. This does not re-run all of `gtk_main()`, it just handles any incoming events. Again, see the documentation I linked to.